# DC-Drop Hyperlynx Simulation: How to decrease current density in certain areas?

Tags: power, pcb, current, power-electronics, hyperlynx

It's the first time I perform DC-Drop simulation in HyperLynx on the power planes of my designs, and I started to feel how much TH vias get in the way of current path in power planes.

Intuitively, I started thinking about some instructions that I can send to the Layout Editor, that might help decreasing the the current density (red areas).

Some of these are just like the notes in the picture below:

1. Rotating Vias
2. Removing Extra TH Vias
3. Re-Arranging Vias

The question is, are these changes really affect anything? and what else can I do?

[image]

DC Current Vectors:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but for others that land here:
Your intuition is correct.  Moving vias out of the way, creating larger solid areas of copper, allows the current to flow better, and have less drops and localized heating.
Removing vias is up to your design.  Redundant vias are usually beneficial for lowering inductance and increasing current capacity.  So they can be a trade.